# R returns factor(0) when predicting with a SVM model

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, predict

My question is quite the same with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723761/factor0-when-using-predict-for-svm-in-r), however, since that seems not to have an satisfying answer yet, I think it is still appropriate to ask again along with reproducible codes.

```
training <- read.csv("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv")[,-1]
testing <- read.csv("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-testing.csv")[,-1]
# Importing data

library(e1071)
# Load the required package for SVM

svm_model <- svm(classe ~ pitch_arm + pitch_forearm + pitch_dumbbell + pitch_belt +
  roll_arm + roll_forearm + roll_dumbbell + roll_belt +
  yaw_arm + yaw_forearm + yaw_dumbbell + yaw_belt,
  data = training, scale = FALSE, cross = 10)
# Perform SVM analysis with default gamma and cost, and do 10-fold cross validation

predict(svm_model, testing)
# R returns factor(0) here
```

I have checked that testing data frame has all columns needed, and no NA exists in those required columns. Please give me some ideas to carry on. Thanks!

Comment: Yes they are of the same type. Thanks for the reminder! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the result of a quirk in the e1071 predict.svm function. While your test data has no missing values for the variables in your model. Every point has missing values.

```
complete.cases(testing)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

You can work around this problem by eliminating the unneeded variables.

```
ModelVars = which(names(training) %in% 
    c("pitch_arm", "pitch_forearm", "pitch_dumbbell", "pitch_belt",
    "roll_arm", "roll_forearm", "roll_dumbbell", "roll_belt", 
    "yaw_arm", "yaw_forearm", "yaw_dumbbell", "yaw_belt"))
test2  = testing[, ModelVars]

predict(svm_model, test2)
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 A  A  B  A  A  A  D  B  A  A  A  C  A  A  A  A  A  A  A  A 
Levels: A B C D E
```